# Difference between private protected and internal protected

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

C# 7.2 introduced the `private protected` modifier, whats the difference to `internal protected`?

From the doc:

> A private protected member is accessible by types derived from the containing class, but only within its containing assembly.

Isn't that exactly what `internal protected` does?

Comment: No, internal protected is accessible in derived classes **AND** the current assembly

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/10/05/c-7-series-part-5-private-protected/

Comment: Internal protected can be accessed from other assemblies, if the type derives from the other. Private protected can never be accessed from other assemblies.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From [Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)

> Protected Internal : The type or member can be accessed by any code in
>   the assembly in which it is declared, or from within a derived class
>   in another assembly.

And

> Private Protected :  The type or member can be accessed only within its 
>   declaring assembly, by code in the same class or in a type that is 
>   derived from that class.

Another useful link  [C# 7 Series, Part 5: Private Protected](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/10/05/c-7-series-part-5-private-protected/)

Comment: The second quote from the Microsoft docs seems ambiguous. I was thinking it meant a private protected type/member can be accessed within its declaring assembly OR in the same class OR in a type derived from that class, which is the same as protected internal. I think replacing the "by" with "by either" would resolve this.

Comment: I would remember it as:  
**Protected Internal = Protected OR Internal** - can be accessed by any code in the assembly OR from within a derived class in another assembly.  
**Private Protected = Protected AND Internal** - can be accessed in the assembly AND from within same/derived class.